# Is testing identity different than testing whether in a tuple?

Tags: python, equality, truthiness

I need to check if a function written by another team returns `True` or `None`.

I want to check for identity, not equality.

I'm unclear what type of check happens when using `in`. Which of the following does `if result in (True, None):` behave like?

1. `if result is True or result is None:`
2. `if result or result == None:`

Comment: Can the function return anything besides boolean or None?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not the same, because identity testing is a subset of what the `in` operator does.

```
if result in (True, None):
```

Is the same as this:

```
if result == True or result is True or result == None or result is None:
# notice that this is both #1 and #2 OR'd together
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations):

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression x in y is equivalent to any(x is e or x == e for e in y)

The in operator tests for both equality and identity, and either one being true will return `True`. I got the impression that you're only working with boolean values and `None`. In that limited case, the `in` operator will behave the same as both of your other snippets.

However, you said you want identity checking. So I would suggest you use that explicitly so your code's intention and what it is expecting is clear. Furthermore, if there is a bug in the called function and it returns something other than boolean or `None`, using the `in` operator can hide that bug.

I would suggest your first alternative:

```
if result is True or result is None:
    # do stuff
else:
    # do other stuff
```

Or if you're feeling defensive:

```
if result is True or result is None:
    # do stuff
elif result is False:
    # do other stuff
else:
    # raise exception or halt and catch fire
```

Comment: "`if result in (True, None)` will behave the same as both of your other code examples." - no it won't. It won't behave like the first snippet because other things can be equal to `True` and `None`. For example, `1.0 == True`. It won't behave like the second snippet because that snippet treats `result` as a boolean directly instead of comparing it to `True` with `==`.

Comment: I think it's more intuitive to check the identity explicitly rather using the membership operator...

Comment: @user2357112 I got the impression that the only possible return values are `True`, `False`, and `None`. If that's the case, then they will behave the same.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Can you reorder your answer slightly to make it clear they aren't the same and the `in` operator behaves like the 2, not 1? I'll happily accept it then.

Comment: @JeffWidman I've reworded it to hopefully make it more clear, but I have to correct your last comment: it's not more like #1 *or* #2. It's **both**.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the **identity operator** (is) and not the membership operator (in):

```
> 1 == True
True
> 1 is True
False
> 1 in (True, None)
True
```

This is a "TL;DR" complement to @skrrgwasme answer :)

Comment: sorry if you meant I copied your original work but we posted around the same time and by the time I posted, your answer wasn't full of editions ;)

Comment: I wrote this on my console. Is there anyway to see the history of deleted comments? I honestly don't recall anyone posting this code snippet neither more than two answers on the thread.

Comment: Fair enough - sorry for the accusation. I'll remove the downvote if you make a small edit. (I can't change my vote until it's edited.)

Comment: that's fine mate, actually think this is a complement to your answer. there are more in-depth arguments in your answer. mine is more a "TL;DR"